# Указатели с C++

Tags: c++

Выделив память так:

```
double* p = new double[b];
```

p не знает о количестве элементов под, которое выделена память. Но освободить всю выделенную память можно так:

```
delete[] p;
```

Как это работает?

Comment: Кто мешает менеджеру памяти записывать это количество в какой-то служебной области, сопутствующей выделенной памяти, например?

Comment: Мне интересно как это точно работает. Или в стандарте C++ это не прописано и каждый компилятор реализует это как хочет?

Comment: Именно - такие вещи стандарт отдает на откуп создателям компиляторов.

Comment: AD&D Game Master Book, rule #1: It's magic!

Comment: В данном случае (тип `double`) в типичной реализации `new[]` просто делает `malloc`, а `delete[]` просто делает `free`, т.е. под капотом работают чисто С-шные механизмы. `malloc` записывает размер блока в служебную область самого блока. К стандарту, однако, это никакого отношения не имеет. Это детали реализации.